# Oiled vs Oil-less turbos

Tags: oil, turbocharger

So the question I have is are there any major benefits to the oil-less turbo technology that exists today? What makes a turbo like this better from a traditional oiled turbo? (Not specific to any car however)

Comment: I would assume oil-less bearings have less rolling resistance, so faster spin up times.

Answer (score -2):

Oil-less turbo's are a idea. COMP Turbos inc. i believe are the only company producing them.

**So Oil-Less turbo Benefits!**

- Don't have to run an oil pressurized line to lubricate the turbos bearing.
- Don't have to worry about exhaust heating that line.
- Don't have to put inline oil filter and or replace.
- Don't have to worry about angle placement of the turbo.
- Don't have to run return oil line.
  [image]

You can run COMP's oil-less turbos anywhere they fit: Rear, Top, Side, Under, Over and in at any angle you'd like!

Only draw back is you have routine greasing with COMP's special grease.

It's really a no brainier! good luck.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to have to downvote this because it's an advertisement. Remove the vendor-specific references and I'll reconsider.